# How to create a 3 dimensional matrix with different lengths using python? (or create a 2D matrix and every data point is a list with unknown length?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I tried np.((3,3),[]) and it went wrong: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0) into shape (3,3)

```
A=np.full((3,3),[])
A[0][0].extend(0)
print(A)
```

I also tried:

```
A=np.zeros((3,3),dtype=list)
A[0][0].extend(0)
print(A)
```

And it gives: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'extend'

:sss

Comment: I know I can just use append function and for loops to realize that but dont we have a more simple way of doing that using exogenous packages? Many many thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a direct answer to your problem, but you could try the following (not sure what your specific needs are)

Try to make your array as large as the largest list and fill it with NA s

```
import numpy as np
length= # length of your longest string here
a=np.empty((3,3,length))
a[:]=np.nan
l=[0,3,5,6,7]
a[0,1,:len(l)]=l
```

with this you might be able to solve your problem, please comment if you have specific needs